# Loading from a text file

Tags: java, android

I'm making an android application that allows a user to add collectibles to a shelf, and the name of each collectible gets held in array called owned. I've written some code (with the help of some folks here) that should save my array into a text file.

That code looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onStop()
{
    try{
        super.onStop();

        FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("savedVinyls", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String vinylString="";
        OutputStreamWriter osWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

        for(int i = 0; i < ownedCounter; i++)
        {
            if(!owned[i].equals(""))
                vinylString += owned[i] + " ";
        }

       fOut.write(vinylString.getBytes());
       fOut.close();

    }
    catch(IOException OE){
        OE.getStackTrace();

    }
}
```

This should, I think, save the array to a file so that it can be read back in later (This part appears to be working correctly, as certain parts of the loading code work)

The code for loading this file back and reading it is as follows:

```
try{

        FileInputStream fileStream;
        fileStream = openFileInput("savedVinyls");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        StringBuffer line = new StringBuffer("");


        while(fileStream.read(buffer) != -1)
        {
            line.append(new String(buffer));
        }

        System.out.println(line);

        String readVinyls = line.toString();
        String[] splitReader = readVinyls.split(" ");
        owned = splitReader;



    }
    catch(IOException OE)
    {
        OE.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I may be going about the file reading/writing all the wrong way, my goal is to make it so that when the user closes the app it saves their collection string, and then loads it when the app is loaded next time.

Currently, it crashes when it tries to load the text file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the stack trace? Try `fOut.flush(); fOut.close();`

Comment: Tried adding .flush(), but nothing changed. The problem seems to be coming from the owned = splitReader; command. That line causes the app to crash every time. On further inspection, it looks like the splitReader string contains a bunch of junk data. Im not sure if that's relevant.

Also, stacktrace looks like it's getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: I can only assume `owned` is a `String[]` too like `splitReader`. assigning them should not cause a crash. Plus, splitted owned on `" "` seems like a bad idea, unless they never contain spaces? The indexOutOfBounds will Not be coming from that line. Basically you are calling `owned[i]` at some point, where `i` is not a valid index.

Comment: Doomsknight, you were right. The issue was coming from a different place in my code. I figured it out and got it fixed. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` it means you are trying to access an invalid index in the array.

Basically you are calling `owned[i]` at some point, where `i` is not a valid index. (Greater than the size of owned)